# Notepad++ RegEx: Move pattern from "String A" into the start of the next "n" lines

Tags: regex, excel, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ to cleanup information in my work and then use it in Excel. After  some cleanup I end with text like the following:

```
01
Ammount 1-1 [tab] Ref 1-1
Ammount 1-2 [tab] Ref 1-2
02
Ammount 2-1 [tab] Ref 2-1
Ammount 2-2 [tab] Ref 2-2
Ammount 2-3 [tab] Ref 2-3
[...]
nn
Ammount nn-1 [tab] Ref nn-1
[...]
Ammount nn-yy [tab] Ref nn-yy
```

> The " [tab] " parts represents tabulators ( \t ).
>
> The "[...]" parts represents "n" lines of text with similar pattern.

When I paste this information in Excel, I get the lines with tabs automatically separated in two cells and then the line with a single number, after that I manually move this number to the (empty) cell before each of the following lines and finally I remove the blank rows, resulting in something like the following text:

```
01 [tab] Ammount1-1 [tab] Ref1-1
01 [tab] Ammount1-2 [tab] Ref1-2
02 [tab] Ammount 2-1 [tab] Ref 2-1
02 [tab] Ammount 2-2 [tab] Ref 2-2
02 [tab] Ammount 2-3 [tab] Ref 2-3
[...]
nn [tab] Ammount nn-1 [tab] Ref nn-1
[...]
nn [tab] Ammount nn-yy [tab] Ref nn-yy
```

This last manual job in Excel may take long time depending on the extension of the reports I'm working with, so I'm looking to know if there's a way in Notepadd++, using Regular Expression, to instantly adjust the desired format to prevent doing it manually in Excel.

Please, let me know if you need any clarification.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Power Query might be able to do that in Excel; certainly some vba arrays and loops could do it.

Comment: This can't be done in notepad++, you have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.